# Freeforms Check Submission is true

Tags: templating, craft3, plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm trying to create a form that adds a cookie so that someone who has submitted the form can see content on the thank you page to protect the download.

Currently I've got this:

```
{{ craft.freeform.form('handle').render() }}

{% set formcook = craft.freeform.form('handle') %}
                    
{% if formcook and formcook.submittedSuccessfully %}
   {# Cookie Will go here #}
{% endif %}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, although I've seen something very similar working on a different project.

Freeforms has very little in their documentation regarding this unless I'm missing something very obvious.

Anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a separate issue causing this, the above works fine.